# Show only specific labels on x-axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to select only specific range of labels to show up in my X-axis. Basically its a Time series and I wanted to select every alternate month to show up in the axis labels. But unable to figure out the way to do so.

Here is my fiddle so far

http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/1n19kwpv/

my code looks like this for the moment

```
var stuff = [{
    "year": 2015,
    "month": 12,
    "s1": 0.38
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 1,
    "s1": 0.39
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 2,
    "s1": 0.43
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 3,
    "s1": 0.40
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 4,
    "s1": 0.39
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 5,
    "s1": 0.39
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 6,
    "s1": 0.38
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 7,
    "s1": 0.37
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 8,
    "s1": 0.37
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 9,
    "s1": 0.35
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 10,
    "s1": 0.37
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 11,
    "s1": 0.36
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 12,
    "s1": 0.37
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 1,
    "s1": 0.35
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 2,
    "s1": 0.36
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 3,
    "s1": 0.37
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 4,
    "s1": 0.38
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 5,
    "s1": 0.35
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 0.36,
    "s1": 0.36
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 7,
    "s1": 0.36
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 8,
    "s1": 0.35
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 9,
    "s1": 0.36
  },
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "month": 10,
    "s1": 0.37
  },



];

var vals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
  var date = new Date(stuff[i]["year"], stuff[i]["month"] - 1, 1);
  vals.push({
    x: date,
    y: stuff[i]["s1"]
  });

}

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var data = [{
    "values": vals,
    "key": "s1",
    "color": "#000000"
  }];
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .forceY([0, 0.5]);

  chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Date (m/y)")
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      if (i % 2 == 1) d3.select(this).remove();
      console.log(i);
      return d3.time.format("%b-%y")(new Date(d))
    });


  chart.yAxis.axisLabel("s1").tickFormat(d3.format(","));

  d3.select("#chart svg")
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
    d3.select("#chart svg").call(chart)
  });

  return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding ticks(d3.utcMonth) for xAxis.

```
chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Date (m/y)")
  .ticks(d3.utcMonth)
  .tickFormat(function(d,i) {
    return d3.time.format("%b-%y")(new Date(d))
  }) ;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1n19kwpv/10/

Comment: ermm...this kind of does it but not completely. I wanted to code the fiddle to show Alternate months only starting from Dec. Like Dec,Feb,Apr,Jun,Aug,Oct,Dec,Feb,Apr,Jun,Aug,Oct. But in the fiddle it still shows Jun-16 then Aug-16.

Comment: Really?! I can see Dec,Feb,Apr,Jun,Aug,Oct,Dec.. and so on. Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/689xy8xy/

Comment: ermmm...yeah https://www.dropbox.com/s/lckywejc5vkwip6/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Oh!! Fixed it. You wanted to remove `-16` part? If so you just had to remove `-%y` in tickFormat. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/689xy8xy/2/

Comment: hehe...naah...I want the dates...if you notice it shows Sep after August, instead of Oct after August.

Comment: Got it. Didn't see that. Is this ok? http://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/689xy8xy/36/. Although, there is a line for Jan, Mar.. etc.

Comment: that works now...thanks. Could you also explain how the code works.

Comment: Sure. Added explanation as comments in this. http://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/689xy8xy/55/. Check if this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer to this is yes, you can, with one possible caveat (below).

According to [this](http://www.d3noob.org/2016/08/changing-number-of-ticks-on-axis-in.html), you can do something like:

```
// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(2)));
```

The one thing I'm not positive about here is whether the timeMonth method is included in d3v3.  It seems like nvd3 doesn't support d3v4 yet, and this example was made in d3v4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nvd3 doesnt have support for D3v4 yet :(